# R - find cut point with SurvMisc cutp() with left truncated data

Tags: r, survival-analysis, truncation

I am trying to find the optimal cut point for a variable using first coxph from the survival package and then cutp() from the survMisc package.My data is left truncated so my coxph is imputed as follows:

```
cph1 <- coxph(Surv(randtime, endtime, recurrence) ~ con + x + y, data=data)
```

however, when I try to use `cutp()` like:

```
cutp(cph1, var=con, plot=TRUE) it gives me an error:
```

Error in 1:D : NA/NaN argument
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

> warnings()
>   Warning messages:
>   1: In Surv(s1[, 1], s1[, 2]) : Invalid status value, converted to NA

If I handle my data as not left truncated, using only `Surv(endtime, recurrence)..)` `cutp()` works well.

Is there a way to find the `cutpoint` with a `coxph` with left truncated data?

Thanks in advance!